# How to fix this stringise error

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

```
#define GETSTRING(s) return #s

enum a_type { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE };

const char* get_data(a_type a) { return GETSTRING(a); }


int main() {

   a_type at = SMALL;

   const char* s = get_data(at);

   return 0;
}
```

I get compiler error:

> main.cpp(5) : error C2059: syntax error : 'return'

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `return GETSTRING(a);` expands to `return return "a";` Not what you want. (Note that you can't use the preprocessor to achieve what you seem to want. It does its work in the compilation phase.)

Comment: @DanielFischer if I remove the double return ie change to: const char* get_data(a_type a) { GETSTRING(a); }  it works at runtime.

Comment: Yes, but it will always return `"a"`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes you are right.  How do I get the string representation of the enums then?

Comment: An array, `static const char* names[] = { "SMALL", "MEDIUM", "LARGE" };` in `get_data` and `return names[a];`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `gcc -E` to output the preprocessed source, you'll see you have an extra `return` in `get_data` :

```
const char* get_data(a_type a) { return return "a"; }
```

Comment: I am having a dumb friday :(  Thanks for that.